# Get string name of passed in var in clojure?

Tags: clojure

How do I get the string name of a 2nd nested var like so?

```
(def bar "abc")
(defn string-var [foo]
  (...))

(= "bar" (string-var bar))
```

Comment: By calling : `(string-var 'bar)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `macro`

```
(def bar "abc")

(defmacro string-var [foo]
  (name foo))

(string-var bar)
=> "bar"
```